# How to change helloworld project to my own in cocos2dx for windows phone 8

Tags: windows-phone-8, cocos2d-x

I am creating a cocos2dx game and i want to give it my own name and image path (mygame.exe). How do i do that? if i go and just change the image path in .xml file it builds the project but doesnt launch it on my device

Answer (score 0):

Not quite sure what you mean by "image path". I wouldn't suggest messing with the project file though for this matter. You can change the image icon and tile in the WMAppManifest.xml by simply browsing for the image you want. In fact you can also change the "display name" of the app there as well. But you can change the entire projects name by renaming the project in the solution explorer.

**EDIT**

Sorry, in my hastiness I overlooked the fact that you are using a cocos2dx template. If the problem is the project does not launch try deploying it manually. Also try renaming the game in the solution explorer then change it in the manifest.

Comment: by imagepath i mean the .exe file. i can change everything else but when i change the .exe file name it doesnt launch

Comment: Sorry I'm not familiar enough with cocos2dx. All I can say is that the name change is not updated somewhere else key to launching the project file. Can you rename the .exe file manually in the solution explorer?

Comment: i can.but when i do the project just doesnt run